# Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

Im getting this warning and cant seem to find the solution, i have tried various answers but still nothing

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-bootstrap\src\sava\UserBundle\Controller\VerUsuarioController.php on line 77 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-bootstrap\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined variable: class in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-bootstrap\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php on line 27
```

my services.yml

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    sava_user.registration.form.type:
        class: sava\UserBundle\Form\RegistroTypes
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sava_user_registration }
```

this is my config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: "@savaUserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'MopaBootstrapBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        less:
            node: /Arturo/bin/node
            node_paths: [/Arturo/lib/node_modules]        
 #       lessphp:
 #           node: ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"]
 #           node_paths: ["C:\\Users\\Arturo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.3.6.jar
            apply_to: "\.css$|\.less$"
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar
            apply_to: "\.css$"
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }


fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: sava\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: sava_user_registration
```

this is my controlleraction

```
  public function modificarUserAction(Request $request,$id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  
    $User = $em->getRepository('savaUserBundle:User')->find($id);
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new \sava\UserBundle\Form\RegistroType(),$User);
    $formulario->handleRequest($request); 
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {       
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $em->persist($User);
                        $em->flush();
                        return $this->forward('savaUserBundle:VerUsuario:vertodos');
    }
    else 
    {
     return $this->render('savaUserBundle:Default:modificarUser.html.twig', array(
     'formulario' => $formulario->createView(),'User'=> $User 
     ));
    }
```

its working fine but i keep getting those errors and have no clue in how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common question for people who are new to dependency injection containers.  You defined your service but then used new RegistroType() to create the instance.  The thinking is that php will somehow realize that you want a service and use the container.  Nope.  The 'new' operator knows nothing about the service container and simply tries to create a new instance without any parameters.  Hence the error message.

You obviously read the "defining form type as a service" section (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services) and I can see where your confusion comes from.  The manual could be a bit clearer perhaps.

Bottom line is that you need to use the form type's alias instead of the new operator:

```
// Replace
$formulario = $this->createForm(\sava\UserBundle\Form\RegistroType(),$User);

// With
$formulario = $this->createForm('sava_user_registration',$User);
```

You will get a different error the first time you try this.  You have a typo in your service definition but I'll leave that for you to debug.